# way to connect windows on intellij to spark on cluster

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

We are trying to connect to spark on cluster from intellij with scala code on windows.
Tried to change the spark-env.sh and this

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Ex").setMaster("spark://XXXX:7077")
```

But couldn't connect throwing error :

```
Could not connect to XXXXX:7077: akka.remote.EndpointAssociationException:        
Association failed with [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@xxxxx:7077]
Failed to connect to master XXXXX:7077
akka.actor.ActorNotFound: Actor not found for: ActorSelection[Anchor(akka.tcp://sparkMaster@xxxxx:7077/), Path(/user/Master)]
```

Can someone tell me the approach how to connect it.

Thanks

Comment: While running on cluster remove `setMaster("spark://XXXX:7077")` and then execute it will run.

Answer (score -1):

It seems to be connection issue between your Windows system and Spark Cluster

- Make sure you set a password less SSH between windows and Spark Cluster

Just in case if you wanted to test it locally on windows system instead of connecting it to Spark Cluster

You need to Install spark on windows and make the following changes in code

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Ex").setMaster("local[*]")
```

**Hope this Helps**

Comment: I want to connect from intellij(windows) to the spark cluster.